# Removing the list style for the Twitter Badge

Tags: html, css, twitter

I am looking to remover the circle bullet list style that is currently applied to my list.  I've tried adding list-style:none; to almost every css id i have relating to the twitter feed and nothing works.  Here is my code.

```
<div id="twitter_div">
<ul id="twitter_update_list"></ul>
</div>

#twitter_div {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:205px;
    height:467px;
    margin-left:11px;
    color:#e5e0bd;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:14px;
    overflow:auto;
}

#twitter_div ul {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-left:16px;
}

#twitter_div ul li {
    margin-bottom:.5em;
    list-style:none;
}

#twitter_div ul a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#666666;
}

#twitter_div ul a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#bfbfbf;
}
```

And as you can see here http://jacobnlsn.com/ it still displays the circles!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, just had to re-upload index.php after adding the style code in the CSS!

Answer (score 1):

`list-style: none` should be `list-style-type: none`.

Comment: list-style: is a shortcut to list-style-type: I figured it out though, since the list is ran by javascript I just had to re-upload the script portion of the code! Thanks though!